# MYSQL Check for record existence while fetching records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've ran into some performance issues with my database structure "or better to say my query instead "

I have a the following table :
`http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/348cb`
And following query trying to fetch certain data, and after that trying to check if there are other records matching my conditions, it's all in the following query.
it is working as expected, the only reason that I'm asking this question is that if there is a way I could increase its performance or use another way to get the results.
As you can see, There two `( SELECT )`'s which trying to check if there are any other records containing current query data.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log AS LIKES 
        WHERE L.target_account=LIKES.target_account
        AND LIKES.type='like' 
) as liked,
( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log AS COMMENTS
    WHERE L.target_account=COMMENTS.target_account 
    AND COMMENTS.type='follow_back' 
) as follow_back,
( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log AS FOLLOW_BACK
    WHERE L.target_account=FOLLOW_BACK.target_account 
    AND COMMENTS.type='follow_back' 
) as follow_back,
L.* 
FROM `log` as L 
    WHERE `L`.`information` = '".$target_name."' 
    AND `L`.`account_id` = '".$id."' 
    AND `L`.`date_ts` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL ".$limit." DAY AND CURDATE()
```

This query takes too much time to fetch the data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the relationship between target id and account id?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thanks for such fast response, `account_id` determines user ID  while `information` ( which has followed by $target_name ) is the person who our `account_id` has followed

Comment: Please go read some of the *many* questions and answers here about query performance - note the information supplied in those which are voted up, down and closed.

Comment: @symcbean I'm sorry if my is any sort of duplicate but I have tried researching about it for like a week and sadly i couldn't find the right way to execute my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to rewrite the query, depending on the relationship between target account and account id.

In the meantime, you want indexes.  The two you want are `instagram_log(target_account, type)` and `instagram_log(account_id, information, date_ts)`:

```
create index idx_instagram_log_1 on instagram_log(target_account, type);
create index idx_instagram_log_2 on instagram_log(account_id, information, date_ts);
```

Comment: Could you please provide a query ? I'm really sorry but your answer did not help me to figure my problem out

Comment: @AliKhaleghi . . . It is the same query.  You need appropriate indexes.

Comment: Whatever I try, even though I would get my expected results, is extremely slow to to execute, the query which i have provided works completely perfect ( in matter of getting results ) but the performance is my concern, I'm grateful for your responses.

Comment: @AliKhaleghi . . . I don't understand your comment.  You need indexes to speed up your existing query.

Comment: Poor english, that must be it, I don't know how i can achieve that sir.

Comment: I've got `#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'target_account' used in key specification without a key length`

Comment: @AliKhaleghi . . . Change the data types to `VARCHAR()`.  Who suggested that you use text for things like account ids?  That is the wrong type for such things.

Comment: The thing is, `information` does not contain account ID's all the time, I use `information` for multiple proposes, but ill change the type and let you know the result.

Comment: WoW ! that completely felt like magic ! Thanks sir it really worked ! while we are at it, my query which i provided in the question, do you see any problems or flaws in it ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff creating `indexes` with `CASE WHEN` will gives better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT SUM(LIKES) LIKES,SUM(FOLLOW_BACK) FOLLOW_BACK,SUM(COMMENTS) FROM
    (
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN L.type='like' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END LIKES,
    CASE WHEN L.type='follow_back' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FOLLOW_BACK,
    CASE WHEN L.type='comments' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END COMMENTS
    FROM `log` as L 
    WHERE `L`.`information` = '".$target_name."' 
    AND `L`.`account_id` = '".$id."' 
    AND `L`.`date_ts` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL ".$limit." DAY AND CURDATE()
    )Z
```

Try the above query.

Comment: I'm sorry, it does look promising but could you complete the query? since `L` has no reference and I'm kinda new to MySQL, I got confused.

Comment: L is referred to `log`  table.I had just modify your query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff sir look at this .. `IS IT PROPER?`

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown column 'LIKES.type' in 'field list'`

Comment: I don't actually know what is wrong but the result were `Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0339 seconds.)` which is unexpected, and btw, i need the result of `L` as well, i tried to putting `L.*` after `SELECT` But `L` was unknown